# KOMA: `\pagestyle{empty}` works but `\pagestyle{plain}` doesn't

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I have headmarks appearing on the first site of a chapter and I would like to make them disappear.

```
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
%\rehead[]{\headmark}  % supresses all headmarks
%\rohead[]{\headmark}  % supresses all headmarks
\rehead[\headmark]{}
\rohead[\headmark]{}
%\ohead[\headmark]{}  % has no effect
%\ohead[]{\headmark}  % suppresses all headlines
\cfoot[]{}  % Remove pagenumber in center of page
%\refoot[\chaptermark {\vline height 13pt width 13pt} \pagemark]{\chaptermark {\vline height 13pt width 13pt} \pagemark}
%\rofoot[\chaptermark {\vline height 13pt width 13pt} \pagemark]{\chaptermark {\vline height 13pt width 13pt} \pagemark}
%\refoot[\chaptermark ~{\vline height 13pt width 1pt} \pagemark]{\chaptermark ~{\vline height 13pt width 1pt} \pagemark}
%\rofoot[\chaptermark ~{\vline height 13pt width 1pt} \pagemark]{\chaptermark ~{\vline height 13pt width 1pt} \pagemark}
\rofoot[]{\pagemark}
\refoot[]{\pagemark}

\pagestyle{scrplain}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}  % has no effect
%\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}  % works, but removes also pagemark
```

Answer (score 2):

The optional argument of `\rehead` and `\rohead` sets the content for the right side of page headers for pagestyle `plain.scrheadings`. Note that `plain` and `scrplain` are aliase for `plain.scrheadings`:

```
\rohead[<content for plain.scrheadings>]{<content for scrheadings>}
```

Unfortunaly we do not know which class is used and if the document is onesided or twosided. And we do not know what the desired result is.

Example for an **onesided document** with chapter title and pagenumber on the right side on "normal" pages and only pagenumber on chapter pages:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% activates pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles% clear predefined contents for both scrheadings and plain.scrheadings
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% starred version sets the entry for both scrheadings and plain.scrheadings

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Example for a **twosided document** with chapter title and pagenumber on the right side on "normal" pages and only pagenumber on chapter pages:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If the document is twosided and the chapter entry and pagenumber should be to the right on odd and even pages (this is unusual):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\rohead{\headmark}
\rehead{\headmark}
\rofoot*{\pagemark}
\refoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your comments and excuse me for not having mentioned that it's a onesided `scrbook` document (which is doesn't matter in this case).

I had missed an important point about *KOMAscript's* `\cfoot[]{}` and `\chead[]{}` macros:
The optional argument in square brackets is intended to set the content of the head- or footline on **plain** pages, like for example the first page of a chapter. Therefore, I one needs to leave out the optional argument like in `\rhead[]{\headmark}` in order to prevent LaTeX from putting a headmark on the first page of a chapter.